# Accessing drawn image on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, game-physics

I want to add an object (spaceship) to a tilemap on which the object can move. I have already created a tilemap into a canvas. And some buttons to navigate them. And one button to create the spaceship on the map.

The problem is, that i can't access my spaceship which is drawn to the Canvas. My idea was, that i create a image class which shall help me to access the image via Jquery. But thats not working. Is there an easy way, how i can move the Picture by clicking on a button?

```
$("#b_generate_ship").click(function() {
    var spaceship = new Image();
    spaceship.src = '\grafiken\/spaceship.png'
    spaceship.className = "spaceship";
    context.drawImage(spaceship , 600, 50);   
    console.log("Ship generated");
});

$("#b_fly_left").click(function() {
    $(".spaceship").animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
    console.log("left flight");
});
```

Comment: There's no objects in a canvas, just pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Pixi.js for this kind of canvas maniuplation, you can create and keep track of a sprite object when drawing on canvas and animate it + a whole host of other awesome things.

http://www.pixijs.com/